# ajax call using Jquery without method name in url

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

What if url in ajax call contains only pagename? Does it call Page_Load method of that page?

```
    $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "PageName.aspx", //No method name
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {        
  }
});
```

If no method name is mentioned,is it same as full page postback?

Comment: u can use $.load to load the page as u want, check this link http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: In the above case, what method is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An AJAX call is simply HTTP GET/POST request to the provided URL. It has nothing to do with the method name. It is asp.net that recognize the method name i.e. web method and passes the call to the appropriate method.

If you don't specify any method name then it will be similar to opening a new URL in your browser. The call will go through the page life cycle and rendered HTML will be returned or if you end the response like

```
Response.Write("Hello");
Response.End();
```

then only "Hello" will be returned by server.

Answer (score 0):

Response is html string, if u want to customize response let using:

```
Response.White("some result");
```

in page_load event

Answer (score 0):

Ajax Function return to error message of `pageName.aspx file`

```
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "PageName.aspx",
       data: "{}",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(msg) {        },
       error:function(msg){
                    $.each(msg,function(i,v){
                        console.log(i+" Value : "+v);
                    });
                   alert( msg.responseText);
                   $("#result").append( msg.responseText); //responseText is PageName.aspx
                }
        });
```

you can handle the exception and append into your result area of same Page.